# Objective-c: Make a cocoa app to simulate media keys

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, media-player

I'm trying to simulate a press of this media buttons by code in a macbook:

[image: Media Keys]

The idea is to pause, rewind... the music with the uibuttons in my app. It's posible to do this? I did't find anything.

Something like this:

```
-  (IBAction)playButtonClick:(id)sender {
    //code here to play music, like if we pressed the physical play media key
}
```

Comment: What are your search terms that ended with no results?

Answer (score 0):

I would draw images for that (probalby in two resolutions, one for retina and one for non-retina, while in most cases a retina version is sufficient) in two variations, one in regular mode and one as if the button is currently pressed.

Then use a simple UIButton object for each of them.

And right, when you create the buttons programmatically, then you can use

```
-  (void)playButtonClick:(id)sender
```

as target for the play button. However, when you want to create and locate the buttons in Interface Builder or Storyboard Editor respectively, then it should be

```
-  (IBAction)playButtonClick:(id)sender
```

which enables the IB to allow you to draw the connection to the action within IB accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! and do you know how can I simulate that button press?

Comment: What do you mean by simulating a button press?

Comment: Pause a song by code, for example, like when I press the pause button

Comment: What do you mean by "simulating a button press?" Are you talking about automated UI testing or are you just courius how to use UIButton - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state method?

Comment: The computer has to think I pressed the play key (F8), and star playing music